# Android Create aligned fields Layout

Tags: android, layout, alignment, android-edittext

Here's my issue I have a login and want to line up the EditText fields.  See the mockup picture attached [image: Align edit text fields].
 I have tried a few ways and cannot figure out how to make the fields lineup.

I really hate layouts in Android I spend more time just messing with things to line up right. Wish they would just scrap it and use something more intuitive, as its more like using tables in HTML.  So in advance thanks for your help and cheers!

Comment: Understand your frustration, also I liked the Android way that handles all layout stuff in xml separate from code. Two edit boxes looks aligned already, can you clarify what you want?

Comment: @bob i think thats a drawing from paintbrush rather than a screenshot of an android activity :P

Comment: Yeah that is a sketch using WireFrameSketcher, best tool out there to prebuild screens and show them to the client to show screen flow and design, worth the $75.00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably play around with [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) and get just what you want.

Here's an approximation with [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="UserID:" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="USER ID" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Password:" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="PASSWORD" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LOGIN" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="REGISTER" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!  What would I do without stackoverflow, this site is the best.  Cheers!

Comment: Only issue with this is that the EditText fields change dynamically when you add or delete text.  Take out both of the text in the fields and the edittext field resizes on the fly to one character wide.

Comment: Change the layout_width attribute of the EditTexts to fill_parent.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you. It doesnt center quite perfectly but it does align well across multiple screen sizes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFFF0000">
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_row"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="25dip">
            <LinearLayout  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Id" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="2" android:textColor="#FF000000"></TextView>
                <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:ems="10" android:layout_weight="1"></EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Password" android:gravity="right" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="2" android:textColor="#FF000000"></TextView>
                <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:ems="10" android:layout_weight="1"></EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/top_row" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="LOGIN" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="REGISTER" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"></Button>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like in my IDE...

[image]

Comment: Liked your approach but went with the one above as the buttons looked a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quick and dirty using TableLayout, just add a TableRow with a TextView and a EditText for the userid and repeat the same for the password.

See http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html