# Problem aligning buttons

Tags: android, user-interface, alignment, android-layout-weight

I want to align those inputs to have two autocomplete box on the right, on a smaller button on their right. However I end up with a large autocomplete (second one) covering everything.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:id="@+id/transport_search"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/transport_autoCompleteFrom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            ></AutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/transport_switchDirection"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transport_autoCompleteFrom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ></Button>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/transport_autoCompleteTo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            ></AutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/transport_go"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transport_autoCompleteTo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From your description, I don't understand what it is you're trying to do.  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout. Below shows two buttons in line:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttons" android:layout_below="@id/aboveControl1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="2" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/otherControl1" android:layout_alignRight="@id/otherControl2" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button10" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ok" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button11" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use RelativeLayout, perhaps the following gets you closer to what you're trying to achieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/transport_search"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/transport_autoCompleteFrom"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="auto 1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/transport_switchDirection"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/transport_autoCompleteFrom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button1" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/transport_autoCompleteTo"
        android:layout_below="@id/transport_autoCompleteFrom"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="auto 2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/transport_go"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/transport_autoCompleteTo"
        android:layout_below="@id/transport_switchDirection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is a screenshot of this layout.

[image]

Also, you may want to take a look at how TableLayout was used for a similar result in [Android Create aligned fields Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642404)